# Custom view made not visible the elements above in xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-custom-view

i have a custom view to show a gif animated image. The problem born when i put in my linearlayout the custom view, the other elements under my custom view aren't displayed. this is my view:

```
public class GIFView extends View{        
private Movie movie;  
private InputStream is;  
private long moviestart;  
private long duration;

public GIFView(Context context) {  
    super(context);
    is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.anim_cerca);  
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    duration = movie.duration();
}  

public GIFView(Context context,AttributeSet set){
    super(context,set);
    is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.anim_cerca);  
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    duration = movie.duration();
}

public GIFView(Context context,AttributeSet set,int def){
    super(context,set,def);
    is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.anim_cerca);  
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    duration = movie.duration();
}

@Override  
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (moviestart == 0) 
        moviestart = now;

    int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % duration);

    movie.setTime(relTime);
    movie.draw(canvas,0,0);


    this.invalidate();
    }                         
}
```

and this is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/sfondo">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="73dp" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" android:src="@drawable/trovachiavi"
            android:layout_width="256dip"></ImageView>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:background="@null" android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:src="@drawable/info_mini"
            android:layout_width="47dp"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutGIF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/avvia_cerca"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:background="@null"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

in the activity i add the custom view to layout with id layoutGIF in this way:

```
LinearLayout lg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutGIF);
lg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
gif = new GIFView(this);
lg.addView(gif, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

what can i do? i need the elements under this!

Comment: You can add your view to the xml using the package name and see how it renders. Hope this helps.

Comment: as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795051/how-to-use-custom-views-in-layout-xml/7795114#comment9507382_7795114 i have a worse problem adding it to xml directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way is using animation.. don't think that gif is solution.. is not supported from every android device!